# Magento 2 Commerce Enable Elastic Search

Tags: magento2, configuration, elasticsearch

**Context:**

As you may know, Magento 2 Commerce(used to be Enterprise) comes with Elastic Search support/integration for catalog search.

**What I've done:**

I have a fully functional ES service (I'm using docker though I think this is not a problem).

I have followed the steps mentioned here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html

And I have a successful connection. (Step 5)

I've re-indexed all. Still, Nothing goes through to Elastic Search.

When I perform a search I get this:

> Notice: Undefined index: suggestions in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/DataProvider/Suggestions.php
>   on line 158

Now this is out of the box Magento stuff.

Am I missing something? Can anyone provide any clues on how to start debuging this?

I do not see anything in the logs when I perform the reindex.

Answer (score 1):

Check if in your searchable attributes there are some with date format, and if yes set them as no searchable and try again.